# Css Matrix vs Transform. Which is Faster?

Tags: css, matrix, 3d, transform

I've been looking on the web for a while and can't find an answer to my question, but hopefully the community knows.

Has anyone test css3 maxtrix compared to css3 transform? I'm using lots of transforms but I see libraries like famo.us and threejs using more of matrices. Is it possible that matrices just have a better performance yield?

Answer (score 1):

Matrix is more faster, but it has worse browser support:

http://jsperf.com/css-matrix-vs-transform-primitives

Comment: By now `transform-primitives` seem to be faster.