# direct 3d transform functions vs. js calculated matrix transform performance

Tags: javascript, css

The following answer shows that matrix transform functions are faster then regular transform:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20892177/157397

That sounds logical to me because the browser will translate transform functions into a matrix anyway.

I am writing a JS Class that renders objects using CSS. In order to be more usable for anyone, I would like to use understandable attributes (the same used in the separate transform functions):

http://codepen.io/meodai/pen/gCbrt

The thing is I would have to calculate the values for the matrix with JS. I would like to know if it is faster to let the browser handle it (like it is now), or should my class calculate a matrix? What would be faster in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, as Seldaek says, don't try to beat the browser on performance, unless there is a real issue.

Second, most of the time, the key issue in performance is rendering, not parsing the value of the property. That would be only noticeable if you are changing your values really fast. And, in that case, probably the easy way to optimize it is to change the transform less often. And leave the smoothing to the browser, via some transition.

And third, you can hit unexpected issues. to say one, the matrices for a 0deg rotation and a 360deg rotation are the same. However, when you are at 359 deg, it's not the same to change that to 360deg than to 0deg. The browser somehow preserves the rotation state here; and you will have problems handling that working only with matrices.

Answer (score 1):

I would not try to beat the browser at the performance game unless you really detect an issue. It's likely they optimize more than you would already, and if not then they might in the future.